# Increase reputation score to give bounties

Tags: feature-request, bounties, low-quality-posts

I hardly look at questions with bounties anymore, on SO. The questions are too numerous and, more importantly,  too low quality.  The last few I've looked at were so poor I would have voted to close them, if that were possible. Perhaps the bar is set too low? Would it be better if the reputation score required to set a bounty were higher?

Comment: If they are low-quality, just downvote them? If everyone feels the same way then there will be no problem soon enough

Comment: Nope. It would be better to have almost empty close vote queue. Then bad quality posts that deserve closing wouldn't survive 2 days to have bounty on them.

Answer (score 5):

This is really a [recency illusion](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recency_illusion); it is not that bounties on low quality posts are a recent thing, it's just that they are brought to your attention now that you are looking at bounties more.

If you wanted to VTC such a question, flag it for moderator attention. State that you wanted to Vote to Close the post, and why, and ask for the bounty to be removed. More often than not, you'll find that not only is the bounty removed, the moderator will happily close the question for you if they agree with your reasoning.

Besides, raising the bar has a downside too: you'll stop all those lower-rep users that use bounties on *good* questions. I don't see that there are enough low-quality posts with bounties to warrant inconveniencing those that are doing it right.

Comment: That would increase the work-load on the moderators. My suggestion would be automatic (if it worked).

Comment: What makes you think such ill-advised questions are limited to low-rep users only? With a higher bar you are also *hurting* lower-rep users.

Comment: Higher reputation users have been around longer, and thus have had more time to learn what bad questions are.

Comment: You'd think that, wouldn't you? But the most recent bounty question I had to flag was by someone with close to 10k rep. The question has since been deleted by the moderator as well.